# How do I get the current url/path in JS for Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to send a request to the current url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window.location.origin`

and append `Window.location. pathname`
to get the full path (No hash or params)

Answer (score 1):

Just send AJAX to empty `""` URL. This will be current url of the page.